# Unable to load local HTML file in Android WebView

Tags: java, android, html, webview, android-webview

I have a WebView. I want to load a local HTML file called helloworld.html. It is located in my drawable-hdpi folder.

Here is my code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/helloworld.html");
```

I get a browser error:

```
The webpage at file:///android_asset/helloworld.html could not be loaded as the file requested was not found. /android_asset/helloworld.html (no such file or directory)
```

How can I resolve?

Comment: Why is html file located in drawable folder?

Comment: Good call. I made a folder called /assets and it works. You should post an answer :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put your HTML file in the assets folder.